# MS Access open record in a form based on current field value

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I have the following New Departure form in MS Access:
[image: image of form]

I want to be able to enter an `Item ID` (we can be sure that the entered value is valid and such a record already exists), and based on the entered `Item ID` open the record from the `1 Inventory` table in this form (this should be the effect of pressing the Open button, or alternatively, pressing Enter).

I tried attaching the following Macro to the `OnClick` event of the `Open` button:
[image: screenshot of macro]

When I enter a value for `Item ID`, and press `Open`, always the last record in `1 Inventory` is opened, no matter the entered value.

The property sheet of the `Item ID` field is the following:
[property sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVR2O.png)
[property sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqwFe.png)

Please help me solve this problem!

Comment: Control used to enter/select filter/search criteria should be UNBOUND, otherwise you change value in existing record or if on new record row, create a record. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question according to your suggestion. Now the problem seems to be with the search criteria in the macro, and I hope it can be solved without using vba. (It seems simple enough)

Comment: It seems you are trying to navigate to a specific record in the same form ([New Departure]), according to the attached image. In this case, a simple VBA code might do the work : recordset.findfirst "[item id]=" & [item id]

Comment: If you want to find a record on same form, use FindRecord action. Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/findrecord-macro-action-1a724e86-1985-48f4-9f77-ea71949f39cd. Why don't you use a combobox instead of textbox? Could use AfterUpdate event instead of requiring user to click a button.

Comment: Or ApplyFilter action https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/applyfilter-macro-action-10ffd4b3-a5c5-4f49-aa44-d2d4550095d1

Comment: As shown in MS docs, WHERE CONDITION needs fully qualified reference to control, not reference to table and field name.

Comment: Images are showing properties of control, not field. Both happen to have same name. I always name controls different from field, such as cbxItemID. Strongly advise not to use space in naming convention. Better field name would be **ItemID**.

Answer (score 0):

1- unbound the form's controls `Control Source` and unbound form's `Record Source`

2- Set `Item ID` Before Update Event In `VBA Editor`, To Check If Item Already Exist.

```vb
    Dim rs     As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [1 Inventory] " & _
        "WHERE [Item ID] = '" & Me.[Item ID] & "'")
    If Not (rs.EOF And rs.BOF) Then
        rs.MoveFirst
        With rs
            Me.[item name] = ![item name]
        End With
    Else
        DoCmd.CancelEvent
        MsgBox "This Item is Not Exist"
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
```

3-and there is no need for `open button` delete it dynamically `item name` Will be entered.

4- use following code to save data to your table `new departure` when you click `save`

```vb
 CurrentDb.Execute "Insert Into [new departure] ([item ID], [Departure Date], [Departure Personel], [Truck Licence Plate], [Departure Comment]) " & _
                      "Values ('" & Me.[item ID] & "', " & Me.[Departure Date] & ", '" & Me.[Departure Personel] & "', '" & Me.[Truck Licence Plate] & "', '" & Me.[Departure Comment] & "')"
```